# Is it good practice to change masterpage at runtime?

Tags: master-page

We have 100 users logging into and using the site simultaneously.

We are planning to change look based on loggedin user's profile property value (true/false). Either set master1 or master2 as masterpage based on this property value.

Is it a good practice to change the masterpage on runtime? Or would it have performance problems?

Comment: it is NOT a good practice!!! What do you need to change? Colors, Fonts, etc?

Comment: yes. only colors and hide divs. can you tell me why it is not good practice?

Comment: because, how many masterpages would you need? 100? regardless, there are better alternatives than changing the masterpage. Eg. You can serve a different CSS/theme to each user through javascript

Comment: There are 2 master pages only.

Comment: Since my requirement is to chagne colors and hide/show div tags on masterpage I went ahead with the option to do this on masterpage via JSOM. But got stuck here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94107/error-while-accessing-the-user-profile-properties-via-js-code. Hence I am thinking of using dynamic masterpage change options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **NOT** a good practice!

> ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application. You can then create individual content pages that contain the content you want to display. When users request the content pages, they merge with the master page to produce output that combines the layout of the master page with the content from the content page.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX

The best solution to change things like colors, fonts, etc is using CSS and JavaScript

Also you could decide to use themes:

> Themes give you a quick and easy way to change the look and feel of any site in SharePoint 2013. They are predesigned collections of web page elements, such as fonts, color schemes, layout, and background pictures that come with SharePoint 2013. In SharePoint 2013, you can apply a theme to a site, and then preview it before committing the change. You can change the theme of a site any number of times. For more information about themes, see Themes overview for SharePoint 2013 in the MSDN Library.
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424397(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Since my requirement is to chagne colors and hide/show div tags on masterpage I went ahead with the option to do this on masterpage via JSOM. But got stuck here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94107/error-while-accessing-the-user-profile-properties-via-js-code …. Hence I am thinking of using dynamic masterpage change options. There are only 2 master pages.

Comment: You can write the user property on the page, hidden, and use that by jquery

Comment: OK, so I should use SOM to fetch property and javascript to hide and change color of divs.